# Display Serial No month wise according to number of data in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display Voucher No in this format **MON/Serial_No**.
I have voucher date saved in table and i want to display month from voucher date and concat with serial no 
**Voucher No format** 
[image: Voucher no]

For example:
If JAN Month has 5 records then display JAN/1,JAN/2,JAN/3,JAN/4,JAN/5
If FEB Month has 3 records then display FEB/1,FEB/2,FEB/3

**here is my Code/Query**

```
SELECT
UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, Cust_Payment.Date_Of_Payment), 3)) as 
'Voucher_No',
Cust_Payment.Date_Of_Payment as 'Voucher_Date'
from Customer_Payments Cust_Payment
```

**output of the query:**
[image: output]

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: change this horrible case to `simply Voucher_No= (FORMAT(Cust_Payment.Date_Of_Payment, 'MMM', 'en-US'))`... then you should edit your question and show the whole query

Comment: @ThomasG It is showing an error "'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.".

Comment: You are probably on version 2008 then. Use this instead `simply Voucher_No=LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, [Cust_Payment.Date_Of_Payment]), 3)`

Comment: Thanks, It worked, but I want serial no next to month according to number of records month wise.

Comment: yes and for this you have to show the whole query and not only a part of the select clause

Comment: Now check the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
(UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, Cust_Payment.Date_Of_Payment), 3)) +'/' +
 CONVERT(varchar(10),row_number() over (partition by MONTH(Cust_Payment.Date_Of_Payment) order by Cust_Payment.Date_Of_Payment)))as 'Voucher_No2',
```

Comment: that was a nice copy/paste of my answer before I have the chance to fix it

Comment: Thanks Rajkumar and @Thomas for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT
     (
      UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, Cust_Payment.Date_Of_Payment), 3)) +
      '/' +
      CONVERT(varchar(10),row_number() over (partition by MONTH(Cust_Payment.Date_Of_Payment) order by Cust_Payment.Date_Of_Payment))
     )as 'Voucher_No',
     Cust_Payment.Date_Of_Payment as 'Voucher_Date'
from Customer_Payments Cust_Payment
```

Comment: It is showing an error "Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint."